# How to move the existing mount point from /usr/local to /usr in Ubuntu 11.04?

Tags: ubuntu, mount, system-installation

I am running Ubuntu 11.04. During installation, instead of `/usr`, I mistakenly assigned `/usr/local` to a separate partition. Now I want to change the mount point to default to `/usr` on boot but I don't want to go through the pain of installing Ubuntu again.

Answer (score 4):

So, if I follow you correctly, you have two partitions (I'm going to call them `/dev/sda1` and `/dev/sda2`, but the names don't matter). The partition `/dev/sda1` is now mounted at `/`, and the partition `/dev/sda2` is now mounted at `/usr/local`. Furthermore, on the filesystem on `/dev/sda2`, the files are the ones that should be under `/usr/local`, while other files that should be under `/usr` are now on `/dev/sda1`.

First, you need to move all the files that are on the wrong partition. The easiest way to do that would be to boot from a live CD or USB, mount both filesystems, and perform the move. Assuming the filesystems are mounted at `/media/sda1` and `/media/sda2`:

```
mv /media/sda2/* /media/sda1/usr/local/
mv /media/sda1/usr/* /media/sda2/
```

Then edit `/etc/fstab` to change the mount point. That is, there is currently a line with something like

```
UUID=1234...  /usr/local  ext4  errors=remount-ro  0 1
```

Change the `/usr/local` part to `/usr`. Now reboot to your new system.

Comment: `/dev/pv/usr` in _while other files that should be under /usr are now on /dev/pv/usr_ should be `/dev/pv/root/usr`

Comment: @dpacmittal: `/dev/pv/root/usr` wouldn't make sense: `/dev/pv/root` is the device, not a directory. Mmm, maybe it's confusing that I used names for the devices, I'll change that to numbers.

Comment: Also moving between different filesystem takes lot of times compared to moving within same filesystem. So `mkdir /media/usr/local && mv /media/usr/* /media/usr/local/`, `mv /media/root/usr/* /media/usr/` would be a better option. No?

Comment: @dpacmittal: Yes, but it's more complicated, and on a recently installed system, there's probably not much in `/usr/local` yet.